# Onload function interferes with page refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have inherited an app that has this code at the top of every page, after the head tag:

```
script src="sorttable.js"></script>
<title>Positions</title>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
function doLoad()
{ setTimeout( "refresh()", 30*1000 ); }
function refresh()
{ window.location.href = sURL; }
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function refresh()
{ window.location.replace( sURL ); }
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function refresh()
{ window.location.reload( true ); }
//-->
</script>
```

This works, and the page refreshes itself every 30 seconds. (As an aside, I don't understand this code - why there's 3 functions with the same name - and why if I remove any of those functions it either doesn't refresh at all, or when it refreshes it get's an 'untrusted connection' error. But that is not my question.)

In some cases I have to run some code when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() { sorttable.innerSortFunction.apply(document.getElementById("FVShort-4"), []); }
</script>
```

My problem is that in the cases when I do have that onload function, the pages no longer refreshes. How can I have both the onload function and still have the automatic refresh work?

Comment: You don't show it, but does your page have `<body onload="doLoad()">`? If so, remove that `onload=` attribute and within your new `window.onload` handler add a call to `doLoad()`.

Comment: YES! That was it exactly. I cannot thank you enough!